# How to use voices from different languages in SSML speech?

Tags: c#, uwp, text-to-speech, ssml

I have a TTS (Text to Speech) UWP Desktop application in which I need to execute speech of different languages in a dialog. The problem is that a  tag can only have a single xml:lang element that overrides the languages of all voices, generating accented speech. Any help is most welcome. Thanks.

```
string strSSML =
  @"<speak version='1.0' " +     
  "xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis' xml:lang='en'> " +
  " <voice name='Microsoft David'> This is a test of different voices in a speech. </voice>" +
  " <voice name='Microsoft Daniel'> Este é um teste de diferentes vozes em uma fala. </voice>" +
  "</speak>";

SpeechSynthesisStream stream = await WAMVariables.Synthesizer.SynthesizeSsmlToStreamAsync(strSSML);
mediaPlayer.Source = MediaSource.CreateFromStream(stream, stream.ContentType);
mediaPlayer.Play();
```

Answer (score 0):

To add different languages in TTS, you will have to add different SSML text for it. The only difference between these SSML texts is the `xml:lang` tag which you've already noticed. The tag makes the SSML work for different languages.

For example, you've posted an en language SSML. If you want to add a french language, please copy the strSSML and name it as strSSML2,  then change the `xml:lang` tag from **en** to **fr-FR**.

Like:

```
 @"<speak version='1.0' " +     
  "xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis' xml:lang='fr-FR'> " +
  " <voice name='Microsoft David'> This is a test of different voices in a speech. </voice>" +
  " <voice name='Microsoft Daniel'> Este é um teste de diferentes vozes em uma fala. </voice>" +
  "</speak>";
```

There is an official sample about TTS on Github: [SpeechRecognitionAndSynthesis](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/main/Samples/SpeechRecognitionAndSynthesis). In **scenario1 - Synthesizing text to speech**, you could perform TTS in different languages. When you check the `Strings` folder, you will see the different language folders, open the **LocalizationTTSResources.resw** file, you could see the strings are the same excepted the `xml:lang` tag. So this is how it works and what you need to do is add some SSML texts with different language tags.

Comment: Roy, with this approach I'm understanding that we would have two streams and we would have to run the two in sequence. The problem is that I need to record a single MP3 of the dialog. Is it possible to do this with two streams?

Comment: @JoseAfonso I think the answer is no. You need to play it one by one during your recording.